# MS SQL Server - Linked table declare linked connection upfront

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a linked server setup and need to pull data from the linked server into my main server. It feels painful to do using the whole server name. I'm trying to see if I can establish the name upfront then use in the rest of my query below.
Such as this:

```
Linkedserver.Database.dbo.Table as Link1
```

then below in my queries be able to have this work:

```
select * from Link1
```

or

```
select * from main-server left join Link1
```

Comment: That isn't how SQL works. You can alias an object in the query, but SQL isn't a programming language, you can't declare a reference and then use that for the remainder of the batch. if you find you're referencing a specific object frequently, take a look at [Synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thank you for this. I've used views in the past, it is a synonym that I was looking for! That solved my issue, thanks for everyone's input!

Answer (score 1):

One method is a view, which does pretty much exactly what you want:

```
create view v_linked
    select *
    from Linkedserver.Database.dbo.Table;
```

You can then reference this as:

```
select *
from v_linked;
```

[Synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) are an alternative mechanism:

```
create synonym linked for Linkedserver.Database.dbo.Table;
```

There are few practical differences between synonyms and views.  However, there are some, such as the effect on existing objects when one is deleted and the DDL triggers needed to track changes.

Comment: Why a `VIEW` rather than a `SYNONYM`?

Comment: @Larnu . . . (1) Views are compatible with any database.  (2) Views are likely to be more familiar to  someone who knows SQL but not the intricacies of SQL Server.  (3) The answer isn't intended to show a preference for one over the other.

Comment: My comment was written before you had added the extra parts on Synonyms. Hence why I asked as the time, as a Synonym (to myself at least) seem liked a more logical choice over a `VIEW` in SQL Server.